# NGINX/Magento 2.3.5/ CSS/JS/Images are not loading

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-404, magento2

Im facing an issue on the Magento fresh package setup.

**Environment details:**
NGNIX, PHP 7.1.19, PHP-FPM

Here is my nginx configuration

```
         server_name  www.abc.example.com;
       return 301 $scheme://abc.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name  abc.example.com;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/abc.example.com.access.log  main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/abc.example.com.error.log;
        error_page 404 /var/www/html/example.tech/404.php;

    
       location / {
    root /var/www/html/vhosts/Magneto/; 
        index  index.php index.html index.htm nginx.conf; 
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
         proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                 proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow_Credentials' 'true';
                 proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
                 proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
       }

    location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias /var/www/html/vhosts/Magento/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/custom_options/ {
    deny all;
}

location /errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}


        location ~ \.php$ {
        root /var/www/html/vhosts/Magneto/;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9043;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 12200;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

}
```

Also tried running following Magento commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you getting HTTP Code 404?

Comment: Yes, i'm getting 404 for assets like CSS/JS/images

Comment: Can you confirm that `/var/www/html/vhosts/Magneto/` is correctly (miss-)spelled? Perhaps, you meant it to be named `/var/www/html/vhosts/Magento/`?